# Ant, Gradle hybrid to publish jar and pom to Artifactory

Tags: java, maven, gradle, groovy, ant

I'm attempting to use Ant for my build and Gradle to publish my jar and pom to Artifactory with some to no luck.  Hope has not run out as I need/want this to happen.

```
task createPom() {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId "${groupId}"
            artifactId 'pluginmanager'
            version "${version}"
        }
    }.writeTo('pom.xml')
}

def pomfile = file('pom.xml')

task publishPom(type: Upload) {
    dependsOn 'createPom'
    artifacts {
        archives pomfile
    }
    repositories {
       "${artifactory_url}"
    }
}

artifactory() {
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = "${repoKey}"
        }
    }
}

artifactoryPublish {
    dependsOn 'publishPom'
}
```

Now it's obviously wonky how I writeTo('pom.xml') and then create (def) the pomfile but that is where I'm getting lost on how to make this work.  On the writeTo piece I can't pass in the pomfile variable and in the publishPom artifacts block when I define the archives as 'pomfile.xml' I get a "Cannot convert the provided notation of an object of type PublishArtifact: pom.xml" error and it tells me to use an "Instance of File".  However, when I pass in the pomfile variable I get a new error, "No value has been specified for property 'artifacts'."

My Gradle task createPom() works but I can't run publishPom().  That might be apparent by now.

Comment: Question - why? Why not simply use [Ivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ivy)?

Comment: Was told that I have to.  I work for a defense company so we have certain limitations on what we can do.  For this project we don't want to convert fully over to Gradle.  We barely ever need to build this so only want to use Gradle for publishing.  This might be a lost cause but I need to prove it out.

We aren't / can't use Ivy anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Maven Publishing plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) already takes care of generating the POM and providing tasks for publishing. Your approach tries to manually create that code.

You can just do the following:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

ext {
    jarFileCreatedByAnt = file('my.jar')
    artifactoryUrl = 'http://localhost:4001/artifactory'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'org.gradle.sample'
            artifactId 'pluginmanager'
            version '1.1'
            artifact jarFileCreatedByAnt
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url artifactoryUrl
        }
    }
}
```

Then run the task `publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository`. Of course the JAR file needs to exist up-front.

Comment: I forgot to mention, and add, my dependencies section in the Gradle script.  I need those to be included in the POM.

Comment: Do you declare the dependencies in your build script or does Gradle not know about them? If you declared them in the build script then the `maven-publish` plugin will automatically add them to the POM when generated. If the dependencies are not known to Gradle then you'll have to modify the POM at build time via [`withXml`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:modifying_the_generated_pom).

Comment: I do.  Thanks for the help!